# Is it possible to make sure that only my plugins output is shown to the enduser?

Tags: plugin-development, login

I'm building a members site, creating my own plugin because existing ones have far too many features. If defined a shortcode to protect a page (members only). If I have no logged-in user, the page shows a login-box. This works fine, however, if the user has some other content on the page, it is still shown. Can I suppress other content?

Relevant part of my plugin

```
add_shortcode('yf-protected', function() {
    global $yf_authenticated; // initially: true

    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $yf_authenticated = false;
        $redirect = "/repertoire/";
        return loginForm($redirect);
    }
});
```

My plugin has a lot of other shortcodes, that won't output anything if yf_authenticated is false. But I can't seem to controll static text on the same page. Is it possible to suppress any other output, thus protecting the whole page?

Comment: have a look at `the_content` filter, but it will ultimately depend on the theme and how it outputs its content. the only way to guarantee that a user doesn't see content is to prevent the theme file from being loaded or redirect away.

Comment: I think I'm looking the wrong way around. I now changed the application logic to make all pages hidden if they are protected. only the login page can be opened when not logged in.